# ExpressJS .param('term', ...) triggers when param not in route URL

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have two routes in an application:

- `app.post('/thing/add', thing.addHandler);`
- `app.post('/thing/:thingId/edit', thing.editHandler);`

(Order as listed)

The edit handler has a `:thingId` parameter that I find and populate using the following (simplified for example):

```
app.param('thingId', function ( req, res, next, id ) {

  Thing.findById(id, function ( err, foundThing ) {

    ...
    req.thing = foundThing;
    next();
  });
});
```

The `.param('thingId')` fires when I post to either route.

Any idea why? I thought perhaps because the word `thing` is a substring of `thingId` and might be getting matched.

Answer (score 0):

If I use regex for the term:

`app.param(/^thingId$/, function ( req, res, next, id ) {..}`

it works as I had intended it to.

Answer (score 0):

Express sees your post to `/thing/add` and thinks that `thingId` now has the value 'add'. It doesn't know that `thingId` is supposed to be an integer value.

To fix this, figure out how to make the routes unambiguously different.

Answer (score 0):

Recomend use PUT method for update or modify documents.

I think you need some like this, bro:

```
app.post('/thing', function(req,res,next){
    new Thing();
    return next();
});

app.put('/thing/:id', function(req,res,next){
    var thingId = req.params.id
     Thing.findById(id, function ( err, foundThing ) {
        req.thing = foundThing;
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; I appreciate the different ways these handlers could be set up, My question was specifically aimed at figuring out how the `app.param()` function is supposed to work though.